# CGMiner - Icarus Detect Failed

Tags: raspbian, cryptocurrency

This question is about bitcoin mining with cgminer.

I have been running raspberry PI with 4 ASICMINER Block Erupter connected to Pi Hub for 5 days with no problems. Yesterday I checked the modules and the idle lights were on and there was no mining. I restarted my raspberry, and now I am getting this error:

```
[2014-04-10 20:23:13] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB0: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
 [2014-04-10 20:23:13] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB1: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
 [2014-04-10 20:23:14] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB3: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
```

I am running the following command:

```
sudo ./cgminer-3.1.1/cgminer --config /home/pi/cgminer.conf -S /dev/ttyUSB0 -S /dev/ttyUSB1 -S /dev/ttyUSB2 -S /dev/ttyUSB3
```

If I connect and run the modules one by one there are no issues. When there are 3-4 I get errors. Those errors change each time I run it, so sometimes its 1 failing other times 2 etc. Also, I am getting this error:

```
[2014-04-10 20:33:04] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to ad
d a port, or have not set up workers
```

Again, there have not been any changes to the configuration (that I am aware of). Any suggestions as to what might be causing this/ how to fix it?